# What happens if you flag a question with bounty?

Tags: support, bounty, close-reasons

Suppose someone post a problem statement question so no attempts on the problem and it also happens that no one flag the question neither so it won't be *on hold* nor *closed* and somebody else (could be the same user that asked) put a bounty of +50 or +100,...

I notice you still have the option to flag the question, the thing is that would the question always remain as it is? or can be put [on hold] and perhaps the [closed] and hence no one can answer the question anymore?

for example like this question 
[Maximizing the ratio of inner products](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3134834/maximizing-the-ratio-of-inner-products)

Comment: Once the bounty expires, the question can be closed.

Comment: If the bountied question should really be closed, then mods can remove (or technically, refund) the bounty and close the question immediately.

Comment: If you flag a question with a bounty, the entire Universe collapses in on itself, and we all die. Don't do it!

Comment: @GerryMyerson hmm.. someone has been watching a lot of Hawking videos.. :)

Answer (score 5):

Questions with a bounty cannot be put on hold. However, moderators can cancel a bounty. (Then, it can be put on hold.)

Yet, usually, we don't cancel bounties. This means, that trying to put on hold a question with a bounty should be reserved for exceptional cases. If there is some actual problem, don't hesitate to bring it up; what I want to discourage though is that standard "lack of context" closures and alike get flagged up.

Note that there is a minimal delay between asking and placing a bounty. Thus, a question that has a bounty at least was initially not considered as close-worthy. Of course, it might have just fallen through the cracks but still there is some initial filter.

Comment: if moderators cancel the bounty, do you give back to the owner ?

Comment: -I want to discourage though is that standard "lack of context" closures and alike get flagged up-. you mean that one should flag in the case I mentioned before?

Comment: Indeed, if a bounty gets canceled the points are given back. (There is no choice.) // No, I mean that one should not flag in this case. Only extremely bad or otherwise directly problematic questions should be flagged if they have a bounty on them. I agree that one might close the question you mentioned, but it's not urgent enough.

Comment: only because of a bounty, psq questions are fine (one should not flag) though that is against the rules of this site. no?

Comment: They are not fine. There are several things to balance tough. A PSQ that is otherwise not overly problematic can stay open as long as there is a good-faith bounty on it. (Of course we'll act against cases that seem like abuse or trolling.)

Comment: What do you mean with not overly problematic? good-faith bounty on it? and what are cases that seem like abuse or trolling? .